# exporting csv from nested python dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{u'results': [{u'bucket': u'Table',
           u'data': [{u'Geography_dst': u'PE',
                      u'avg_bps': 5054970470.588235,
                      u'device': u'taco',
                      u'as': u'Telephone Company',
                      u'next_hop': u'Telephone Companu',
                      u'key': blah,
                      u'max_bps': 6613494000,
                      u'p95th_bps': 6280622000,
                      u'timeSeries': {}},
```

[truncated for brevity]

I can't seem to figure out how to parse this dictionary into a csv.  I am having trouble figuring out how to make a column out of each key in the 'data' tuple and have the rows populate from the appropriate values:

```
 device,as,nexthop,Geography_dst,max_bps,p95th_bps,avg_bps
```

(and yeah, I'd prefer not to have the 'key' or the timeseries tuples in the csv at all, but I figure that will be apparent once I figure out how to work with this data structure).

Thanks!

Comment: You only want to save the 'data' part into a file, and ignore what is above?

Comment: yep, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) that writes fields from `dict` based on the instructions given to constructor:

```
import csv
COLUMNS = 'device,as,next_hop,Geography_dst,max_bps,p95th_bps,avg_bps'

d = {
    u'results': [{
        u'bucket': u'Table',
        u'data': [{
            u'Geography_dst': u'PE',
            u'avg_bps': 5054970470.588235,
            u'device': u'taco',
            u'as': u'Telephone Company',
            u'next_hop': u'Telephone Companu',
            u'key': None,
            u'max_bps': 6613494000,
            u'p95th_bps': 6280622000,
            u'timeSeries': {}
        }]
    }]
}

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, extrasaction='ignore', fieldnames=COLUMNS.split(','))
    writer.writeheader()
    rows = (row for bucket in d['results'] for row in bucket['data'])
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Output in `output.csv`:

```
device,as,next_hop,Geography_dst,max_bps,p95th_bps,avg_bps
taco,Telephone Company,Telephone Companu,PE,6613494000,6280622000,5054970470.588235
```

In above `csv.DictWriter(f, extrasaction='ignore', fieldnames=COLUMNS.split(','))` creates a writer object. `extrasaction` instructs it to skip the keys which are not present in `fieldnames`. `fieldnames` is ordered list of keys that you want to write from each `dict`. [`writeheader`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter.writeheader) just writes the column names, you can skip this if columns are not needed.

`rows` is a generator expression that iterates over the results and objects within a result. It returns the dicts you want to write one by one. Finally the generator is given to [`writerows`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) that writes all the dicts returned by generator to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I took the the assumption that you want to save only the data part and that it consists of multiple dictionaries with the same key. Here is the code that can convert and save the 'data'.

That would solve the problem:

```
import csv

big_dict = {
    'reslts': [{
        'bcket': 'Table',
        'data': [{
            'Geography_dst': 'PE',
            'avg_bps': 5054970470.588235,
            'device': 'taco',
            'as': 'Telephone Company',
            'next_hop': 'Telephone Compan',
            'key': 'blah',
            'max_bps': 6613494000,
            'p95th_bps': 6280622000,
            'timeSeries': {}
        },
        {
            'avg_bps': 5054970470.588235,
            'device': 'taco',
            'as': 'Telephone Company',
            'next_hop': 'Telephone Compan',
            'key': 'blah',
            'p95th_bps': 6280622000,
            'timeSeries': {},
            'Geography_dst': 'XE',
            'max_bps': 6613494000
        }]
    }]
}

my_dicts = big_dict['reslts'][0]['data']

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    keys_saved = False
    for my_dict in my_dicts:
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
        if not keys_saved:
            w.writeheader()
            keys_saved = True
        w.writerow(my_dict)
```

Please note that this handles the case when you have the same keys everywhere, but not necessarily in the same order.

Comment: Generally, the order of keys in a dict is not predictable, and can change each time the program is run, so you shouldn't pass `my_dict.keys()` to ` csv.DictWriter`. Instead, you should pass a fixed list of keys.

Comment: The order of keys in a dict is not random-per-run, but it might change if Python were upgraded. Alternatives to a fixed list: pass `sorted(my_dict.keys())` to fix an ordering, or use `collections.OrderedDict` to ensure that keys are always in the order they are created (which is defined by the data source).